# Where Spring-Security jar for MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Where can I download jar file for spring-security?

```
1. org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.messaging.MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry

2. org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.socket.AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer

3. org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
```

I did not see any link to download.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't find spring-boot-security because it is actually [spring-boot-starter-security](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-security).

Comment: I usually use maven ([Getting Started - Building Java Projects with Maven](https://spring.io/guides/gs/maven/)), and I suggest you also read [Getting Started - Serving Web Content with Spring MVC](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/).

Answer (score 0):

You can find the first two classes in [spring-security-messaging](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-messaging)

The third one is simply [spring-boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/)